# How to avoid flickering in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

how to avoid flickering in treeview,

when some property of nodes is gettng updated,
or the node is added

Comment: What technology? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: which platform are you using (Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc) and which TreeView control? Also please post some code of how you update your treeview.

Comment: WPF and ASP.Net will not have this problem because of the technologies. This must be WinForms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
try
{
    treeView.BeginUpdate();

    // Update your tree view.
}
finally
{
    treeView.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: this wont be applicable because single time the function is called the single file will get updated.....

Comment: What do you mean by a single file? Could you please provide sample code of how you update the treeview with the question?

Comment: i have a filesystemwatcher... for each filecreated event the nodes property in treeview get updated in treeview.... i could not call begin and endupdate.. because for each file tat event will get raised

Comment: The reason the treeview flickers is that you're doing multiple updates (e.g. more than one property or more than one node) with one update. Please try my code sample and see whether that helps. If it does not help, please provide sample code of how you update the treeview with the question.

Comment: Was the pun intended?

Answer (score 2):

I was fighting this, too.  Here is my solution for those of you searching out there.  Add this to your treeview subclass.

```
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
    private const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

    private const int skipMsgCount = 5;
    private int currentMsgCount;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL)
        {

            var nfy = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
            if (nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK)
            {
                currentMsgCount++;
                if (currentMsgCount % skipMsgCount == 0)
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                return;
            }
            if (nfy == SB_ENDSCROLL)
                currentMsgCount = 0;

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I got the idea here: [treeview scrollbar event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/3ea9a4d3-0614-4d4f-a861-3cb30ca1bda0/)

Basically I am just ignoring a significant percentage of the scroll messages.  It reduces flicker a lot for me.